# using Intrinsic Locks in SYNCHRONIZATION

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

**Suppose d is the object we're using to invoke wait. When a thread invokes d.wait, it must own the intrinsic lock for d — otherwise an error is thrown. Invoking wait inside a synchronized method is a simple way to acquire the intrinsic lock.**

so is this means that two threads cannot invoke wait() at the same time? what do intrinsic lock here mean [mentioned it as Monitor]? but how 's monitor implemented to achive mutual exclusion?

once the thread invokes wait does it holds object forever?
if so how about other thread using that lock for notifyAll()?

**if we need to acquire object during notifyall, then why all waiting threads notified?
shouldn't it notify threads waiting on that object alone?**

Any code to explain is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so is this means that two threads cannot invoke wait() at the same
>   time?

Correct two thread cannot invoke wait() at the same time.  However, once one thread is in wait(), another thread can acquire the same lock and enter a wait() state soon after.  You can have any number of threads WAITING on the same object, but only one really holds the lock.

> what do intrinsic lock here mean [mentioned it as Monitor]? but
>   how 's monitor implemented to achive mutual exclusion?

Only one thread can be running while holding a object.  Other thread can be blocking trying to acquire the lock and more can be wait()ing on it.

> once the thread invokes wait does it holds object forever?

The opposite, it gives it up or another thread can acquire it almost immediately.

> if so how
>   about other thread using that lock for notifyAll()?

If you call notifyAll() on the object, all the wait()ing thread are woken in turn.  Those threads can only acquire the lock one at a time and will re-acquire the lock as soonas they can.

> if we need to acquire object during notifyall, then why all waiting
>   threads notified?

That is what notifyAll does, it is considered safer than using notify, which wakes a random one as it is less prone to coding errors.

> shouldn't it notify threads waiting on that object alone?

That is what it does.

---

You should note that;

- before you notify()/notifyAll() you should perform a state change.  You should also wait() inside a loop which checks that state change.  You need to do this because a) wait() can miss a notify(), b) it can wake spuriously c) another thread might grab whatever you ahve done and it might need to wait again.
- over the last 9 years, there has been greater use of High Level concurrency classes.  Using these classes mean you don't need to work with Threads, Queues,  wait() and notify() directly.

Comment: why can't it use something like if threads wait(objA) [register somewhere] notifyall(objA) might notify only list of Threads that waits for this particular object [objA]?

Comment: @Dineshkumar That is what I meant by; "That is what it does."

Comment: i guess i got confused because of this: Always invoke wait inside a loop that tests for the condition being waited for. Don't assume that the interrupt was for the particular condition you were waiting for, or that the condition is still true. what does it mean?

Comment: It means you can't just wait() and expect it to be deterministic.  Unless you also check a state change, this can fail for a number of reasons. i.e. you have to check that what you have been waiting for has actually happened before and after you wait()

Comment: sorry, i don't get it! we do notify when the state changes. so why need to check again?

Comment: @Dineshkumar Because the state might have changed before you started waiting (in which case you will have missed the notify), you might wake from waiting when it hasn't actually changed, another thread might have woken first and taken whatever you were waiting for and you might have to wait again.

Comment: Thanks for your great help. explaining all for me. awsome explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> Invoking wait inside a synchronized method is a simple way to acquire
>   the intrinsic lock.

Wait does not provide the lock on an object rather it makes the thread to wait to listen about the lock release when other thread calls notify. Thread gets the lock when it enters the guarded//synchronized block. Synchronzied block/method allows to take the lock if available otherwise thread cannot enter those code block.

Answer (score 0):

Locks are not held forever, according to the javadoc:

> The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes execution.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `wait()`, you **release** the intrinsic lock on that object, until another thread calls `notify()` or `notifyAll()` on it. At that point, the JVM will wake one of the threads waiting, and automatically reacquire the lock on that object.

So to answer your question, yes, multiple threads can `wait()` on the same object.